# Is there a way to see 'imports' in a .NET binary?

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, .net, automation

Programs such as [Detect It Easy](http://ntinfo.biz/index.html) or IDA can show functions and libraries (`DLLs`) imported by a binary in the case of `C/C++` binaries. I have a collection of `.NET` malware that I'm analyzing and would like to see the imported functions and DLLs for these binaries. I've noticed that `_CorExeMain` is the only thing that I can see in the `imports` section with tools such as `IDA` for such binaries. I'm aware that I can decompile the `.NET` binary in a tool like `dnSpy` and manually read the function calls but I would like an automated and fast of doing this such as the `imports` section in `IDA`.

Is there a way to see functions imported from dynamic libraries for `.NET` binaries?

Comment: use proper tools - `dnSpy` or other decompiler that's targeting .NET programs.

Comment: I already mentioned `dnSpy` in my question. I still have to manually find the library calls by reading the code. Is there a section in `dnSpy` that I'm missing where all the function calls are shown in one place?

Comment: @learnerX so do I understand correctly that you want the list of all methods that a specific .NET program uses based on its references?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik yes, I would like to see the list of all library function calls like in the `imports` view in `IDA`

Comment: to get native function calls might be tricky if impossible (maybe some magic  done after methods are JITed) - to get the list of managed function calls might be possible to get.

Comment: Using reflection you can find all the `PInvoke` attributes, which will probably give you the closest thing to the list of native "imports".